# Alfresco - Search Workflow with like cluase (or contains!)

Tags: search, workflow, alfresco

I've developed a simple webscript that accepts in input some paramenters and returns a list of workflows that matches the conditions. This is a simplified version:

```
WorkflowInstanceQuery workflowInstanceQuery = new WorkflowInstanceQuery();
Map<QName, Object> filters = new HashMap<QName, Object>(9);
if (req.getParameter(MY_PARAM) != null)
    filters.put(QNAME_MYPROP, req.getParameter(MY_PARAM));
workflowInstanceQuery.setCustomProps(filters);

List<WorkflowInstance> workflows = new ArrayList<WorkflowInstance>();
workflows.addAll(workflowService.getWorkflows(workflowInstanceQuery));
List<Map<String, Object>> results = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>(workflows.size());
for (WorkflowInstance workflow : workflows)
{
    results.add(buildSimple(workflow));                         
}
```

This is working perfectly, but now i'd like to have as a result all the workflows that match in like or contains the property in input.
For example if the property in input is valued "hello" i would like to have in output of the webscript the workflows that have that property with values such as "hello" or "hello Dear" or "Say hello" and so on...
This is actually working with search for content in Advanced Search of Alfresco Share...how to implement with WorkflowInstanceQuery?!

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco's ActivitiWorkflowEngine class uses Activiti's HistoricProcessInstanceQuery for the search and it is using "variableValueEquals" method to add the custom properties so it will never behave as a "LIKE" clause.

Comment: See [here in the Alfresco source code](https://github.com/ecm4u/alfresco-ce-repository/blob/master/root/projects/repository/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/workflow/activiti/ActivitiWorkflowEngine.java#L1803) for the offending `variableValueEquals` call behind this

Answer (score 0):

There are two things which you need to consider here.Workflow Model and Content Model.You need to understand both of the things here.Whatever properties are created in content model are stored with documents and not with workflows.Workflows are having task model associated with it.So logical its going to difficult to find filter workflows based on properties of document.Because there is no association between them, unless and until you have explicitly created it.

If you want to filter based on properties than it should exist in workflow model associated with workflow task.That too you have to filter based on task of workflows.Because each task will have its own property.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried putting wildcards for your filters  parameter?
filters.put(QNAME_MYPROP, "*"+req.getParameter(MY_PARAM)+"*");

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this not work!If I insert wildcard "*" the search not work even if i search for the exact string in MY_PARAM!